# Why does SPICE include a NULL file?

Tags: c, null, header-files

I have been working with the spice3f5 source code and I noticed that there exists an ominous `suffix.h` header file which is included in almost every .c file. This file contains nothing except the comment `/* Null file */`. What is the purpose of this? Does it even have a purpose? I could not find anything about it online and it has been bugging me!

Answer (score 1):

> This is based on assumption and *partly* personal experience

That header file is there for expanding the flexibility and robustness of the code base.

Once you need to add a new MACRO, forward declaration, you can simply add that in `suffix.h` file. No need to change any existing source `[`.c`] file, as the`suffix.h` is already there.